# RWD theme - What's controls the size of an image after clicking the swatch?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

When I'm on the category page I have 2 swatches for an image. When I click on either of the swatches, it shrinks the size of image to the default magento square. I need it to stay the same size as the base image that comes up by default.

1. How do I define this? Where? I see in `list.phtml` there is a
   `$_imgSize` which I have set.
2. How do I prevent it from cropping and adding whiteness around the
   image?

I imagine that this shouldn't be too difficult but I can't for the life of me find out where this is being controlled.

Answer (score 1):

Please review mentioned `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file and search for `$_imgSize`. There is a bunch of instruction text describing `$_imgSize` variable there. You can just adjust this variable value to use different size for image thumbnail.

As regards swatch size, you can adjust it in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Configurable Swatches`.

Answer (score -1):

Should just be a css attribute that controls it, check out `skin/frontend/rwd/enterprise/css` or `/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css`, sorry not familiar with the `css` files so I dunno where specifically it is.